# How do I undo hadoop fs -rmr?

Tags: hadoop, data-recovery

I accidentally just deleted a massive directory on my hadoop cluster using

hadoop fs -rmr /path/to/directory/

how do i undo this.

I didnt have the trash collection for hadoop setup yet "/user/X/.Trash" . I just set it up after this massive mistake. Is there any built in tools i can use to recover the directories?

---

Edit:

I forgot that i have a snapshot of just my client node from the cluster from before i deleted everything. What will happen if i revert to this snapshot? I know the files weren't actually deleted/overwritten just the ability to access that location in memory. Will restoring this fix it? I dont want to do anything without being sure.

Comment: If you don't have the trash setup, then I don't think you can recover anything.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to recover a file if trash wasn't setup or if skipTrash was used would be if you have HDFS snapshots created. Then you could recover the file from the snapshot location.

Answer (score 0):

Always use skipTrash command, while deleting your file, you can retain your file within 4 days only.

Command-
hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash filename file path

Comment: This answer isnt telling anything about undoing a -rmr command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).